# Bootstrap jQuery Tabs are not working in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
  //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
  // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
  //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
  // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="dropdown messages-menu">
  <!-- Menu toggle button -->
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Hai, I was trying to develop the code in which I want the `dropdown-menu` to close when I click outside of the `dropdown-menu`, I succeed in this but here I got a problem when I insert `nav-tabs` in `dropdown-menu` the tabs are not working.

here's the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/gz15c52a/

Thanks in advance

## zeasts

Comment: remove your java-script code then you will able to click on other menu options

Comment: I want that code also, cause when I click on the `dropdown-menu` Items the `dropdown-menu` shouldn't close. @NeerajSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stop propagating the event on click of li, this is causing the selection of tab to break. Since you need to stop event propagation to avoid the closing of the drop down, you will have to select the tab manually.You can achieve this by below code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
//The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
// therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
   //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
   // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a').on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).tab('show')
 });
});
```

**Updated Snippet**

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
//The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
// therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
   //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
   // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });
   
 $('.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a').on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).tab('show')
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="dropdown messages-menu">
  <!-- Menu toggle button -->
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: it is creating a problem to `li.dropdown`, even after closing the `dropdown-menu` also the `li.dropdown` is still in `active` mode. @deep

Comment: do you want to display home tab as selected tab every time you close the drop down ?

Comment: no, it is not about the tabs of jQuery, but the parent li.dropdown is having the active, ill update the fiddle link in my next comment. @deep

Comment: Ok, will have a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/gz15c52a/3/, heres the fiddle link, please click on the `Messages` and click `view all`  in the `dropdown-menu` than close the `dropdown-menu` but the active is still displaying to the `li.dropdown` @deep

Comment: OK , got your issue in the fiddle you have 2 drop downs that is why this issue has occurred we will have to bind the event with the correct element.                                                                                         $('.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a').on('click', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     $(this).tab('show')
   });                                                                                                                             This way you can select the correct elements, fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gz15c52a/5/